# How to validate 17 digits in array of VIN numbers from form in php?

Tags: php

I have the following validation code that runs after my form is submitted:

```
foreach ($_POST['vin']) as $vin_value ) {
if(strlen($vin_value) != 17) {
echo "VIN is not 17 digits"; 
echo "VIN is " . strlen($vin_value) . " digits";
echo "VIN value is: " . $vin_value;
} else {
mail($admin_email, "Auto Quote Request", $email_body);
echo "Thank you for contacting us!";
}

}
```

I am trying to make sure the individual vin's ($vin_value) of my vin[] array are exactly 17 digits.  Right now when I submit the form no message is displayed at all.  What's going on here??  And I realize this code just checks for characters, not digits.  Thanks.

html form input:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputVIN" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Vehicle Identification Number</label>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <input class="form-control" id="inputVIN" placeholder="Must be 17 digits." type="text" name="vin[]">

  </div>
</div>
```

The input is an array. This is to accommodate the possibility of multiple vin numbers. There is an option to add another form field with the name of vin[]. All the inputs relevant to this question have name="vin[]" . To reiterate, at first there is one form group with name=vin[], but the user can click a button to add more. This is why I am using an array in the first place. So I want each element in the array (the $vin_value)to contain exactly 17 characters. That is why I am using a foreach. I hope that provides enough context.

Comment: What's actually in the `$vin` variable when this code fails?  It's probably not a 17-character string...

Comment: name="vin[]", that's an array...

Comment: `var_dump($vin)`. if it doesn't say `string(17) "...."`, then you don't have a 17-character string, and your `!=` is properly succeeding.

Comment: exactly ctype_digit — Check for numeric character(s)

Comment: **Note:** strlen() returns the number of bytes rather than the number of characters in a string. Are you using a multi byte character set. Echo out the result of `strlen($vin)` to see what it is calculating the length as that may give you a clue

Comment: Try to use mb_strlen

Comment: this would be simple if((preg_match("/[^0-9]/", '', $str)) && strlen($str) == 17) it cheks number entered are only numbers and length should be 17 digits

Comment: @user5198569 It would be helpful if you gave some feedback

Comment: *One of those "talk amongst yourselves"* type of questions. Or is that "fight amongst yourselves"? Voted to close as unclear.

Comment: Alright so I forgot to mention that the vin[] is an array to allow for multiple vin's to be submitted

Comment: Well in that case the code you wrote is useless. I assume you will rewrite it. So we can close this one

Comment: @user5198569 you will need to iterate over the vins using a loop, strlen of an array returns null and emits an error

Comment: @user5198569 if you want your question to be reopened, you will need to show us your full and relevant code, including the HTML form. You see, when you post a question with nothing for us to go on but GUESS, you're not helping anyone, including yourself. You're behind your computer, we're not. Do that, and reopen votes may start coming in. This takes longer; you should have thought about that from the "get go". ;-)

Comment: I edited the question.  Not sure what seeing the html form is going to do but I guess I will include anyway.  I did mention that the name of the form input was vin[] which should have clued in everyone that it was an array, but I should have been more clear.

Comment: You need to provide sample strings too and how they are entered in the input. 123abc? 123A, 123B? AB123-A, AB321,123,def? The more information you give the good people, the easier it will be to help you find a solution. The less you give, the more they guess, remember that the next time you're in a restaurant and they don't have a menu ;-)

Comment: The input is just 17 digits.  Like so: 11111111111111111

Comment: *"The input is just 17 digits. Like so: 11111111111111111 "* - So why do you need a foreach/array then? are there multiples being entered? if so, you need to provide a sample of that. Sorry, but you're really not making this easy for us/me, and I am trying to help you. If you can't be specific, then I won't continue here and will move on, good luck, I sincerely wish you well, *cheers*. On an added note, if your input contains a space, then that will account for it failing; use `trim()`.

Comment: Let me rephrase:  The input is an array.  This is to accommodate the possibility of multiple vin numbers.  There is an option to add another form field with the name of vin[].  All the inputs relevant to this question have name="vin[]" .  To reiterate, at first there is one form group with name=vin[], but the user can click a button to add more.  This is why I am using an array in the first place.  So I want each element in the array (the $vin_value)to contain exactly 17 characters.  That is why I am using a foreach.  I hope that provides enough context.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just a thought, does your `<form>` have `method="post"`?

Comment: Also, in case you aren't already aware of this, prior to 1981 VINs were not 17 characters. Your application may not need to deal with any vehicles that old, but just FYI.

Comment: This will never work as long you have a typo in your code . Hard to see, but the output will be nothing. `foreach ($_POST['vin']) as $vin_value ) {` you have an **unnecessary closing bracket** after **$_POST['vin'])** <- . remove it and you'll be fine.

Comment: Yes I just caught that typo a few minutes ago.  Thank you for the tip Don't Panic I will have to look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take an guess that the value `$vin` is an array, null or undefined and thus the function call `strlen($vin)` is returning zero every time.

see documentation for [strlen here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)

Change your code to the following to debug the values:

```
if(strlen($vin) != 17) {
  echo "VIN is not 17 digits"; 
  echo "VIN is " . strlen($vin) . " digits";
  echo "VIN value is: " . $vin;
} else {
  mail($admin_email, "Auto Quote Request", $email_body);
  echo "Thank you for contacting us!";
}
```

---

edit possible solution number 2:

> strlen() returns the number of bytes rather than the number of characters in a string.

As suggested by a comment by chernyshevsky in the strlen docs do the following:

pass the string through utf8_decode() first:

```
if(strlen(utf8_decode($vin)) != 17) {
  echo "VIN is not 17 digits"; 
  echo "VIN is " . strlen(utf8_decode($vin)) . " digits";
  echo "VIN value is: " . $vin;
} else {
  mail($admin_email, "Auto Quote Request", $email_body);
  echo "Thank you for contacting us!";
}
```

> utf8_decode() converts characters that are not in ISO-8859-1 to '?', which, for the purpose of counting the number of characters will work.

Comment: don't understand the downvote - this did contain the correct answer. @user5198569 was passing an array to the function

Comment: `I would take an guess that the value $vin is an array, null or undefined and thus the function call strlen($vin) is returning zero every time.` You know that from comments. But you did not care ! After delete the typo here : unnecessary closing bracket after **$_POST['vin'])** <- .Everything works fine

Comment: @moskito-x that's not the case - the OP said in his comments that he wanted to pass an array of values. I suggested that he use a loop + the answer I proposed above.

Comment: @moskito-x also I do care otherwise I wouldn't spend my time posting an answer :) and am happy at least OP seems to have solved the problem

Comment: Ok @moskito-x I spent a few more min looking into this - the question had been heavily editing after initially being closed. I didn't have any chance to see that the OP had introduced a typo in the for each statement in an edit after my answer was posted. I only just woke up and didn't get a notification that the question had been edited or reopened :)